# Mounting Google Cloud Filestore accross multiple available zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-eks, google-cloud-filestore

I'd like to achieve the same setup as [image: AWS EFS Setup]. That is I'd like to have a single Filestore instance available in all availability zones for high availability and fail over. However it seems like Filestore can only be created in a single availability zone as stated here [GCP Filestore Regions and Zones](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/regions)

> Filestore instances live in zones within regions. A region is a specific geographical location where you can run your resources. Each region is subdivided into several zones. For example, the us-central1 region in the central United States has zones us-central1-a, us-central1-b, us-central1-c, and us-central1-f. For more information, see Geography and Regions.
>
> Some Google Cloud APIs, including the Filestore API, use the concept of locations, which can represent either regions or zones. For Filestore instances, locations map to zones.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transparent High Availability feature has not yet been implemented on Google Filestore.

I found a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/124781731) about it. It states that a workaround would be for users to implement their own redundancy by having two filestores in different zones and each write going to both of them. But as of now it is not possible to implement in GCP.

Answer (score 1):

GCP introduces the feature very recently in [their blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/introducing-filestore-backups):

> If data in a zone is inaccessible, users can restore the data using the regional backup and continue working in any available zone.